# "Hidden" Form fields won't hide on Android or iOS with CSS or JavaScript

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile

I have a form with a number of fields. Some of the fields are visible and some have a class (hidefield) which sets them to to "display:none;". The problem is that on some iOS devices (iPhone 5) and some android devices, the calculation form fields that are supposed to be hidden are visible.

I have tried
a) adding the !important declaration
b)increasing CSS specificity
c) adding  -webkit-appearance:none; - because I thought maybe that was overriding the display none
d) using JavaScript `$('.hidefield').hide();`

None of these have worked. I've tested on a few live devices and through browserstack. On the iPhone 5 (the fields are hidden on the 5s) and on the Android phone (I tested a number of the latest versions through Browserstack), the form fields are visible. I don't know if the class is somehow removed or what and maybe that's why it's not picking it up.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm using Gravity Forms on a WordPress site.

Here is a preview of the page so you can see my code: http://greenjobinterview.com/?page_id=15948&preview=1&_ppp=db1f23d81e

I appreciate any help!

Comment: All the fields after "Question 6" all the way to "You could save" should be hidden.

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at on that page, maybe you can recreate on a smaller test case?  Just a guess.. but I'd try disabling your place-holder plug-in, if you are using a plug-in for that part (to move the field labels inside the fields).  Also try removing any other plug-ins that use JavaScript, until you find the problem.

Comment: Here is a screenshot from browerstack on an iphone 5 which shows the fields that are supposed to be hidden: http://i.imgur.com/i1n3IMp.jpg

Comment: I believe this overrides your !important in your CSS: body .gform_wrapper ul li.gfield {display: block;} -- so on desktop browsers the only reason they are hidden is because of your JavaScript.  So on some phones you probably have a JavaScript error causing your JavaScript to not run (I see errors in the FireFox console).  Try "increasing CSS specificity" again, and make sure you are more specific than: body .gform_wrapper ul li.gfield

Comment: Oh, and fix your JavaScript errors, or you'll have plenty of weird problems like this.  http://greenjobinterview.com/wp-content/themes/greenjobinterview/js/infographic_scripts.js  -- line 23, throwing an error in FireFox console when I load that page.

Comment: @eselk Thank you so much for your help. I cleaned up the JS errors and that didn't do the trick, but I greatly increased the specificity and that did it!  It's still odd to me though that the "!important" declaration was being overwritten by something and only in older mobile browsers. Even adding the inline style via JS wasn't doing it. Very odd. If you want to post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks again!